# Azure : How to know the total storage at a subscription level

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am looking for a approach to figure out the total storage at a subscription level ( Not at storage account level)

Storage for all Block Types (by region ?)

Answer (score 0):

> Storage for all Block Types (by region?)

If you’d like to get total storage of Azure (ARM) storage accounts for a subscription, you can [list all the storage accounts under the subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/StorageAccounts/List) first.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts?api-version={api-version}
```

And then you can  group storage accounts by `location` and [list all containers under the specified account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-containers2).

```
GET https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list
```

After you get the container, you can [list blobs under the specified container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs) and compute the total size of block blobs (based on `BlobType`).

```
GET https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?restype=container&comp=list
```

***Updates:***

We can get total block blobs size at storage account **container** level by checking **Container properties** on Azure portal.

[image]

*Block blobs count and size*

[image]

Comment: Hey Fred, Thanks for the reply. So, we have to use the API to get these details and there is no way getting these values from Azure portal or from services like Monitor etc.. ?

Comment: I do not find a direct way to get total storage of block blobs at a subscription level, but we can get total block blobs size at storage account container level on Azure portal. For details, please see my updates.